# Foursquare bug: oauth login leads to 404 error if account is connected to Facebook

Tags: facebook, oauth, foursquare

We've been wrestling with a weird problem some of our users are having when attempting to login to Vizify using their foursquare account via oauth. If the user's foursquare account is connected to their facebook account and they are logged in to facebook, the oauth process leads to a 404 error. If they are either not logged in to facebook or their accounts are not connected, the process works as expected.

The process is as follows:

1) We hit the oauth url: 
https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=OUR_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=OUR_REDIRECT_URI

2) Browser is redirected to: https://foursquare.com/facebook-login?continue=/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=OUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=OUR_REDIRECT_URL

3) Browser is redirected to: https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=CLIENT_ID&domain=foursquare.com&origin=1&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D27%23cb%3Df373b9bef%26domain%3Dfoursquare.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Ffoursquare.com%252Ff3ba6cde18%26relation%3Dparent&response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Ccode&sdk=joey

4) Browser is redirected back to: https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=OUR_CLIENT_ID

**Note in step 4 the response_type and redirect_uri parameters are missing.** This request is what leads to a 404 response.

The problem can be reproduced with other apps as well. For example I confirmed with foodspotting as well:

- Clear cache and cookies
- Sign in to facebook
- Sign up to foodspotting.com
- Under your foodspotting account settings, click to connect the Foursquare app
- Bam - 404

The clearing of the cache/cookies is required because the foursquare bug here happens when they try to auto log you in via Facebook, and right before they do that first attempt, they set a cookie "disableFacebookAutoLogin" that prevents them from attempting the auto login a second time. This cookie appears to persist even after signing out.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the un-minified javascript from foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate we've tracked down the bug. The problem code comes from the following function:

```
fourSq.auth.Autologin = {
  maybeFacebookAutologin: function () {
    window.fourSq.config.enableFacebookAutologin && (!$.cookie("disableFacebookAutologin") && !fourSq.api.models.companion.user.UserUtil.isLoggedIn()) && fourSq.facebook.getFacebookApi(function (a) {
      a.getLoginStatus(function (b) {
        if (b === fourSq.facebook.FacebookApi.State.CONNECTED) {
          var c = (b = location.href.match(/[\?&]continue=([^&]+)/) || location.href.match(/https?:\/\/[^\/]+(.+)/)) ? b[1] : "/";
          a.loginWithPermissions(void 0, function () {
            var a = fourSq.stats.Action.build(fourSq.stats.action.Action.AUTOLOGIN);
            fourSq.stats.logActionWithDelay(a, function () {
              $.cookie("disableFacebookAutologin", "1", {
                  expires: 1,
                  path: "/"
              });
              fourSq.util.redirect("/facebook-login?continue\x3d" + c)
            })
          })
        }
      })
    })
  }
};
```

The problem line is

`fourSq.util.redirect("/facebook-login?continue\x3d" + c)` **which does not escape c**.

This leads to a situation like this (simplified URL for the sake of exposition):

`http://foursquare.com/facebook-login?continue=/cool/beans?foo=bar&baz=bam`.

See the issue?  All query parameters in the continue URL (except the first one) are instead intepreted as query parameters to /facebook-login!

The correct code should be:

```
fourSq.util.redirect("/facebook-login?continue\x3d" + encodeURIComponent(c))
```

Which will generate the correct output:

http://foursquare.com/facebook-login?continue=%2Fcool%2Fbeans%3Ffoo%3Dbar%26baz%3Dbam

Comment: Hmm, does look like a bug. We're taking a look on our end.

Comment: For the record, foursquare has pushed a fix for this bug. Awesome fast turnaround guys, thanks!